# Iterating and looping over multiple columns in glm in r using a name from another variable

Tags: r, loops, glm

I am trying to iterate over multiple columns for a glm function in R.

```
view(mtcars)
names <- names(mtcars[-c(1,2)])

for(i in 1:length(names)){
  
  print(paste0("Starting iterations for ",names[i]))
  
  
  model <-  glm(mpg ~ cyl + paste0(names[i]), data=mtcars, family = gaussian())
  summary(model)
  
  print(paste0("Iterations for ",names[i], " finished"))
}
```

however, I am getting the following error:

```
[1] "Starting iterations for disp"
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ cyl + paste0(names[i]), data = mtcars,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'paste0(names[i])')
```

Not sure, how I can correct this.

Comment: Avoid naming objects similar to built-in functions like `names`. Your first line almost redefines the `names` function but with package scope you are not overwriting `base::names`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpg ~ cyl + paste0(names[i])` or even `mpg ~ cyl + names[i]` is not a valid syntax for a formula. Use

```
reformulate(c("cyl", names[i]), "mpg")
```

instead, which dynamically creates a formula from variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to build your model formula dynamically from string you need `as.formula`. Alternatively, consider [**`reformulate`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html) which receives response and RHS variable names:

```r
...
    fml <- reformulate(c("cyl", names[i]), "mpg")
    model <-  glm(fml, data=mtcars, family = gaussian())
    summary(model)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

glm takes a formula which you can create using as.formula()

```
predictors <- names(mtcars[-c(1,2)])

for(predictor in predictors){
  
  print(paste0("Starting iterations for ",predictor))
  
  model <-  glm(as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ cyl + ",predictor)), 
                           data=mtcars, 
                           family = gaussian())
  print(summary(model))
  
  print(paste0("Iterations for ",predictor, " finished"))
}
```